# PHP Parse Date String

Tags: php, date, parsing

If I've got a date string:

```
$date = "08/20/2009";
```

And I want to separate each part of the date:

```
$m = "08";
$d = "20";
$y = "2009";
```

How would I do so?

Is there a special date function I should be using?  Or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) will do the trick for that:

```
$pieces = explode("/", $date);
$d = $pieces[1];
$m = $pieces[0];
$y = $pieces[2];
```

Alternatively, you could do it in one line (see comments - thanks Lucky):

```
list($m, $d, $y) = explode("/", $date);
```

Comment: list($m,$d,$y) = explode("/", $date);

Answer (score 18):

One way would be to do this:

```
$time = strtotime($date);
$m = date('m', $time);
$d = date('d', $time);
$y = date('Y', $time);
```

Comment: Ah, but your response is more robust.

Comment: Strtotime does not always work because of the timestamp constraint. Say you want to parse World War I, you cannot convert 28/08/1914 to a valid timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

Check out PHP's [date_parse function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php).  Unless you're sure input will always be in a consistent format, AND you validate it first, it is much more stable and flexible, (not to mention easier), to let PHP try to parse the format for you.

e.g.

```
<?php
//Both inputs should return the same Month-Day-Year
print_r(date_parse("2012-1-12 51:00:00.5"));
print_r(date_parse("1/12/2012"));
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a given format you should use a [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '08/20/2009');
$m = $date->format('m');
$d = $date->format('d');
$y = $date->format('Y');
```

Note you can certainly use only one call to [DateTime::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
$newFormat = $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it always like that? Or will it be in any sort of file format?

Try strtotime.

Something like:

```
if(($iTime = strtotime($strDate))!==false)
{
 echo date('m', $iTime);
 echo date('d', $iTime);
 echo date('y', $iTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
list($m, $d, $y) = explode("/", $date);
```

A quick one liner.

Answer (score 0):

For internationalized date parsing, see IntlDateFormatter::parse - http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php

For example:

```
$f = new \IntlDateFormatter('en_gb', \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($f->parse('1/2/2015'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Dominic's answer is good, but **IF** the date is **ALWAYS** in the same format you could use this:

```
$m = substr($date,0,2);
$d = substr($date,3,2);
$y = substr($date,-4);
```

and not have to use an array or explode

Bill H

Comment: Why would one want to avoid explode?  *IF* the date is *ALWAYS* in the same format, explode will work perfectly, and as @GiDo implies, will be self documenting in terms of intent.  If one wants to avoid the array, then `list` the elements out to distinct variables.